# how to create a pdf with a transparent background

Tags: color, backgrounds, transparent

How do I create a pdf file with a transparent background?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \nopagecolor 
    hi
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work since `\nopagecolor` resets the page color to the default background, but how do I make it transparent, as one can with e.g. a png image?

Comment: I was under the impression that a pdf would default to transperant. You don't need any special code for it. Open the pdf in an image-editor, and you will see that it is transperant.

Comment: Hmm.  In gimp it opens with a white background.

Comment: I tried opening a transperant pdf with gimp and you are right, it turns into a white background. Might be a bug in Gimp.

Comment: You can use [Image Magic](http://www.imagemagick.org), it will display a transparent background with `\nopagecolor` or if background is not explicitly set (which is transparent by default).

Comment: Image Magic is not supported in Windows 7 32-Bit...any help for those whoe have windows 7 32-Bit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\nopagecolor` of `pdftex.def` (and LuaTeX) disables the page color, it does not use any other color like white. Compare and look closely at the cropped images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  % Page 1
  \nopagecolor
  \verb|\nopagecolor|
  \newpage

  % Page 2
  \pagecolor{white}
  \verb|\pagecolor{white}|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1 with \nopagecolor]

> [image: Page 2 with \pagecolor{white}]

The second page has a white background.

The first page does not have a background, which can also be verified by the page stream operators for the first page with some added comments:

```pdf
stream
0 g 0 G  % set black as fill and stroke color
0 g 0 G  % set black as fill and stroke color
0 g 0 G  % set black as fill and stroke color
BT  % begin text
/F15 9.9626 Tf 148.712 657.235 Td [(\134nopagecolor)]TJ  % Write "\nopagecolor"
0 g 0 G  % set black as fill and stroke color
0 g 0 G  % set black as fill and stroke color
ET  % end text
endstream
```

The white background of GIMP adds the white background. I have not seen an option to disable it (version 2.8). If the white color is only used for the background, then option "Colors → Color to Alpha" can convert white back to the alpha transparency channel.

Comment: Does this work for pdflatex? I get `Undefined control sequence. l.5 \nopagecolor`.

Comment: @Lance `\nopagecolor` is defined in `xcolor.sty` (2022/06/12 v2.14) or `color.sty` (2022/01/06 v1.3d).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this might help someone using Overleaf.
Create a file called latexmkrc. Populate it with the following:

```
END { system('convert -density 600 -background transparent -flatten output.pdf pages.png'); }
```

Compile this file.
In the logs, scroll down and select other logs and files. Your transparent file is "pages.png".