# How can I create a transparent background in a logo?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I want to use TiKZ to create a logo for use in letterhead, posters, or whatever. Obviously, a transparent background is ideal, so the logo will fit in nicely wherever it is. So, I did this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % Allows us to wrap text around a circle
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % Hopefully, allows transparent background

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
    
    \fontspec{Times New Roman}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[opacity=0] (-3.5,-3.5) rectangle (3.5,3.5);
        \end{scope}
        
        % Draw double circle with text in the gap
        
        \draw [
               ultra thick,
               rotate=200,
            ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
            
        \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
            
        \path [
            decorate,
            decoration={
              raise=-1.4ex,
              text along path,
              text align={center},
              text={|\Huge|2017}
            },
          ] (180:30mm) arc (180:360:30mm) ;
          
        \path [rotate=224,
                    decorate,
                    decoration={
                          raise=-4.5ex,
                          text along path, 
                          reverse path,
                          text align={fit to path},
                          text={|\Huge|Look at this logo}
                          }
                ] (90:35mm) arc (90:360:35mm) ;
            
        % Include some more words
            
        \node[label=above:{\huge MORE}] at (0,1) {};
        \node[label=below:{\huge WORDS}] at (0,-1) {};
        
        % Include an image
        
        \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{some_file.png}} at (0pt,0pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- I was hoping that the `scope` with the 0 opacity would do the trick, but it didn't.
- Then I used Preview (Mac) to export the PDF to a PNG, hoping that that would work. It didn't.
- I tried to use Inkscape to set the alpha channel to transparent, but... It didn't.
- I tried to just include the `tikzpicture` in the poster I was creating, with a `resizebox` around it to scale it, but that just produced horrific distortion.

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323751/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-a-transparent-background) suggests using GIMP, but GIMP isn't available to me for reasons that are above my pay grade.

What else can I try?

## Update

I did also try including the `tikzpicture` code in the poster code, and using `scale` to adjust the size, but that didn't work because of font size issues (I reset `normalsize` to 60pt, which means that the logo can't work because it specifies `huge` and `Huge` fonts.

Comment: How exactly did you resize that tikzpicture? tikzpicture can also resize it self (the scale option)

Comment: @daleif I resized it with `resizebox`. It didn't work well. 

The problem with `scale` is that the main text of the poster is very large (`\normalsize` = 60pt). So when I try to add the logo code into the poster code, and the logo design uses the font sizes `huge` and `Huge`, that's based on a normalsize of 60, but the drawn circles are still 3cm across.

Theoretically I could redo the whole thing, redrawing the circles to fit the large text, etc., but that defeats the purpose of having a logo made up.

Comment: Is the background transparent by default? Not if you convert to PNG and don't take care, of course, but the picture has a transparent background to begin with. (If your page colour is red rather than white, say., this should be pretty obvious.) Of course, if you put it on a white page, it then has a white background, just as it will have a red background, if you put it on a red page.

Comment: Please don't post examples which require proprietary fonts unless the fonts are essential to the question.

Comment: @cfr Will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The background of `tikzpicture`s is transparent by default. Avoid filling it and it stays that way.

Here's a demonstration, with TeX fonts and images available in all standard distributions substituted for your proprietary and custom ones, which I don't have.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-logo.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % Allows us to wrap text around a circle
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [
  ultra thick,
  rotate=200,
  ] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
  \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
  \path [
  decorate,
  decoration={
    raise=-1.4ex,
    text along path,
    text align={center},
    text={|\Huge|2017}
  },
  ] (180:30mm) arc (180:360:30mm) ;
  \path [rotate=224,
  decorate,
  decoration={
    raise=-4.5ex,
    text along path,
    reverse path,
    text align={fit to path},
    text={|\Huge|Look at this logo}
  }
  ] (90:35mm) arc (90:360:35mm) ;
  \node[label=above:{\huge MORE}] at (0,1) {};
  \node[label=below:{\huge WORDS}] at (0,-1) {};
  \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{tiger}} at (0pt,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \pagecolor{blue}\includegraphics{\jobname-logo}
\end{document}
```

I compiled `\jobname-logo.tex` with XeTeX. You didn't say, but that's the only engine compatible with the code you posted and a current TeX installation, so I'm assuming that's what you're using. I used pdfTeX to compile the main document, because it is fastest.

The logo has a transparent background:

[image: logo with transparent background on blue page]