# standalone does not produce a transparent background

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, transparent

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382726/240454, the author claims that the background of tikzpictures are transparent by default.

In this MWE, for me, using either pdflatex or xelatex, I remain with a white background. Is there a problem with my installation?

```
\documentclass[crop,multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[red,line width=1mm,fill=blue] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex
```

The result is then, after exporting the pdf as png using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC:

[image]

Comment: The PDF generated by the above code should have no background and if you import this PDF into some other document and place it over another picture, there should be no white background visible. However, Acrobat (as well as most other PDF viewers) will always show a white background. You can disable this in Acrobat by checking File > Preferences > Page Display > Show transparency grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for this option in my Acrobat settings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF's can and will have transparency since PDF 1.4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Transparency

Your code generates a PDF with transparent background(Correction: No background). Apparently, your export settings of Adobe Acrobat makes your PNG white.

I compile your code, and use:

```
convert triangle.pdf triangle.png
```

to create this PNG:

[image: Window showing a triangle.png with transparent background]

(Here shown viewed in Mac preview)

`convert` is from ImageMagick: https://imagemagick.org (free for all platforms)

Comment: It's true, the default export to png using Acrobat inserts a white background. I achieve the same using IM. Thank you.

Comment: @XGDragon No need to write thank you. -just upvote/accept :o)