# Transparent background using `standalone` class

Tags: pdftex, standalone, convert

I'm using the `standalone` class to produce an image. I'd like to have the background transparent instead of white. I'm compiling with:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape formula.tex
```

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=0.5 pt, convert=size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
n \cdot m \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\begin{cases}
    \underbrace{n+n+\ldots+n}_\text{m \text{volte}} & \text{se } m>0 \\
    0 & \text{se } m=0.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I'm using

> GraphicsMagick 1.4 snapshot-20190423 Q16
>   http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/ Copyright (C) 2002-2019 GraphicsMagick
>   Group. Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.

In the past when I had ImageMagick installed on my system it has always worked.

Comment: Did you check your log-file for error mesages? Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323751/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-a-transparent-background

Comment: I don't see anything wrong: https://pastebin.com/kkghYmqk

Comment: I get transparent background. Can you please add some detail about your setup?

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. and GraphicsMagick 1.4 snapshot-20190423