# Fixed Tengwar text

Tags: beamer, fonts

It is possible to have a fixed Tengwar text, so that anyone, even without the proper fonts, can compile a document with this text?

I have installed and followed [this guide](https://github.com/nbeaver/tengwarscript-install-guide), and I can compile documents with Tengwar. I'm looking to put a fixed Tengwar text in Beamer document shared between others, that don't have the fonts.

Comment: Not sure why, once its installed, you can't use it in whatever documents you want.  But, if nothing else, you can compile Tengwar as `standalone` documents and include elsewhere as graphics.

Comment: they either need the fonts, or you should include the text as an image, the other systems need _something_ to tell them the letter shapes.

Comment: You ought to be able to put a copy of the open-source font in the project directory.

Comment: You say in the first sentence that you want people without the fonts to be able to compile the documents. They should be able to install them from CTAN, like any other font. You say in the second paragraph that you want to share the Beamer document. If it’s compiled to PDF, it would embed the font subset it uses.

Comment: Yes @Davislor, but I would like to save the hassle of installing fonts, since the text is only decoration. Actually I'm sharing the Beamer source.

Comment: Thanks, that’s clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [the recommendation of Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517097/fixed-tengwar-text#comment1307696_517097), I decided to compile a `standalone` Tengwar text. [It is possible to specify a transparent background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323754/162307) with `\nopagecolor` using the `xcolor` package.

```
\documentclass[convert={convertexe={convert}}]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{tengwarscript}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\color{white}
\nopagecolor

\tengwarannataritalic
\tengwa{254}
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tando\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tumbar\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tungwe\Tumbar\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\tengwa{255}\\
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tthuule\Troomen\Tquesse\TTthreedots\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedungwe\TTthreedots\Tumbar\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tesse\Tkern{-0.2}\Tmalta\TTrightcurl\Textendedcalma\TTdot\Ttelco\TTdot\Tquesse\Troomen\Tparma\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl\\

\end{document}
```

[image: tengwar with orchid color scheme]

To get the right colors for a Beamer presentation using the `orchid` theme, I used [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer), and apply them to the text. Then, in the Beamer, I just `\includegraphics` the output Tengwar text PDF (named `one_ring.pdf`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{one_ring}}
    This inscription says in Black Speech:

    \textit{Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul,}\\
    \textit{Ash nazg thrakatulûk agh burzum-ishi krimpatul.} \\~\\

    Translated, the words mean:

    \textit{One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them,}\\
    \textit{One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer with tengwar text]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/181614)

Comment: How should the answer be improved?

Comment: Add an MWE and a example of the output

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking about making one.

Comment: As an alternative to specifying the background color, you could make the background transparent and overlay the text.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks.